# Ck editor language plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my project .Add a plugin language but that plugin is not working

More : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgmgj.png

Comment: did you read it? http://rev.ckeditor.com/ckeditor/trunk/7483/_samples/ui_languages.html

Comment: this is for ui language But i need editor content language change

Comment: i dont understand. why you need change content language. if you change keyboard its works as well. because ck editor file encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: because in my project editor used for 3-foreign country.so admin only know english so language change will help admin to work .

Answer (score 0):

Language plugin **will not** translate your text.

The only purpose of that plugin is to wrap your text with `<span lang="fr">...</span>` tags, which makes it a structured content. It helps various assistive technologies used for web pages. See the W3 note about [Language information and text direction](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1).

Comment: but in ckeditor official site , demonstrate a language change method. visit link:http://ckeditor.com/addon/language

Comment: Yes. It demonstrates semantic language change if you write your text in that language first :) CKEditor offers **no** content translator. Sorry.